# Date must follow format: yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZZZZZ

Tags: java, date, datetime

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZZZZZ");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String executionDate1 = df.format(new Date());
Date executionDate = df.parse(executionDate1);
```

It gives 20150208153355.141+0530 in string format. By changing it into date format it becomes: Sun Feb 08 15:33:55 IST 2015.

I am trying to implement Immunization Calculator Engine (ICE). The code gives evaluation time for immunization recommendations:

I need to use this date format in:
CdsOutput result = service.evaluate(input.getCdsObject(), scopingEntityId, businessId, version, executionDate);

when I run it in Netbeans8.0.1 (jdk7) (glassfish server4) gives error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: tS2TSInternal(): getValue() is null; must follow format: yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZZZZZ Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP12Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP12Fault.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy462.evaluateAtSpecifiedTime(Unknown Source)
    at org.cdsframework.cds.service.OpenCdsService.evaluate(OpenCdsService.java:320)
    at org.cdsframework.cds.service.OpenCdsService.evaluate(OpenCdsService.java:228)
    at org.cdsframework.cds.service.OpenCdsService.evaluate(OpenCdsService.java:210)
    at org.mypackage.immunizations.processRequest(immunizations.java:185)
    at org.mypackage.immunizations.doGet(immunizations.java:273)
```

How do I get date in date format yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZZZZZ ?
I followed previous answers to write this code, but I am still getting errors.

Comment: `getValue() is null` - this is your problem it seems. Your parsing is fine, you just can't parse `null`. Also what does the server log say? (As stated in the exception?)

Comment: How is method service.evaluate declared, especially what are the parameter types?

Comment: Server.log gives this error which is a bug in glassfish4 as reported here: [link](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236515) and its solution here:[link](https://www.java.net//node/700037). I used tomcat7 as a work around and got "getValue() is null" error. Tomcat server log has: org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header. Do I need to work on my wsdl again?

Comment: Hi laune. service. evaluate is declared as CdsOutput. The parameters declared are: input as CdsInputWrapper, scopingEntityId, businessId and version as String and executionDate as Date.

Comment: tomcat7 server log file gives error: org.opencds.vmr.v1_0.mappings.utilities.MappingUtility tS2TS internal():get value is null must follow yyyyMMddHHmmss,SSSZZZZ. I can't import mappings.utilities. I am looking for appropriate opencds jar file for this. Can anyone please suggest this?